# Is there any software/application contain all the brand phone emulator,so that i can test phone apps on emulator?

Tags: mobile, emulation

Ask for help/share information.

Recently i develop some phone apps in ios,android,blackberry,window,nokia and others.
But i want to noe is there any software/application contain all the type of emulator,so that i can test it on different model of devices to see the layout.Something like Nokia-Remote Device Access, of coz inside only have nokia phone emulator.What i want is software/application that contain all hte emulator(iphone,samsung,backberry,etc) to use it.Hope anyone share out information no matter paid/free software. 
thank you

Comment: Consider asking on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/, since your question is not about code.